# Problems with white space in solr

Tags: curl, solr, solr4

I have this query to a *solr4.8.0* server (using `curl`):

```
curl -g "http://192.168.0.70:8983/solr/solr_db/select?q=*:*&fl=some,fields,here&start=0&rows=5&fq=first_filter:first_value&fq=time_filter:[2016-11-21T22:00:00Z%20TO%202016-11-22T21:59:59Z]&fq=third_filter:third-value&fq=forth_filter:forth%20value"
```

As you can see, for the forth query filter (`forth_filter:forth%20value`), there is a value which contains white space. I escaped this using the URL escape method (`%20`). I used before this escape with `time_filter`.

This query gives an error:

> "error":{
>
> "msg":"no field name specified in query and no default specified via 'df' param",
>
> "code":400}
>
> }

**Problem description**:
The error is due to `forth_filter`. I know this because if I remove it, everything works. And also, if I remove all other filters, but keep it, it still doesn't work, resulting in the same error.
Can anybody guide me how to fix this problem?

N.B. I'm querying *solr* via *PHP*, but in order to fix this, I try it via `curl` first. Querying via PHP library, gives the same error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape spaces by either enclosing the whole value within `""`, `forth_filter:"forth value"` or using `\`: `forth_filter:forth\ value`.